# How can I determined if I'm within an AIR app through Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I'm seeking a method that tells me whether my code is running inside an AIR app or not. Something a lot less tacky than polling an AIR-only method. So far, searching the docs has been unfruitful. Anyone know of such a method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said above check [playerType](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#playerType) within [Capabilities](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Capabilities.html):

```
switch (Capabilities.playerType) {
 case "Desktop":
  trace("inside Air");
 break;

 default:
  trace("inside Standalone or Browser");
 break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with [flash.system.Capabilities](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) ?

This gives you lot of information about the player running your swf.